# Laravel 4 - update pivot table. Error 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sync() '

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, updates, pivot-table

I'm trying to update my pivot table 'actividad_material' and I'm getting the error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sync()

This is my code:

```
$actividad = Actividad::find($id);
$material_id = array(
    'material_id' => Input::get('material_id'));            
$actividad->materials->sync($material_id);
```

I've tried passing $material_id and not, with () and without, 'attach' instead of 'sync',... I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it is because you are trying to pass an associative array into  the `sync()` where it should be an array containing the `ids` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses are missing:

```
// here:
$actividad->materials->sync($material_id);
```

Check this:

```
$actividad->materials; // collection Object

$actividad->materials(); // Relation Object
```

So you need:

```
$actividad->materials()->sync($material_id);
```

Comment: I have a new problem with that... If I have saved some 'materials' related to my 'actividad', when I try to upload, it only uploads one of the new materials selected. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: What do you mean by upload?

Comment: Ok man, I got it. My problem was that I didn't pass my data as an array from my form... Thanks!!!